# What are possible fixes when MacBook IS on same wifi network as iPhone, but MacBook says it ain't?

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

[image]My iPhone and MacBook Pro ARE on the same network but I am getting a message that they are not. I usually make phone calls directly from my MacBook so this has proven to be an annoyance. What possible troubleshooting steps could I try or what should I make sure is clicked on or off to enable the MacBook to recogonize that it IS on same network as iPhone? Thx.

Comment: Do you have *AP isolation* enabled on your router?  What are the IP addresses of your Mac and iPhone?

Comment: This issue occurs when I am in the office that I rent...I won't be there until tomorrow so I can't check right now.

Comment: If your rental includes WiFi, I would bet that they have AP isolation enabled as a security measure.  This means no two devices on the WiFi can communicate with each other.